# Android:setting priority to application

Tags: android

I have wrote an android application.There have a service, From the boot up itself the service running in the background.I need to set high priority to my application.Is there a way to set high priority to android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setThreadPriority()` function on the [process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#setThreadPriority%28int,%20int%29) object. Also you can set the priority of an individual Thread with `setPriority()`

EDIT:
You can use this:

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(newPriority);
```

or this

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(newPriority);
```

Comment: ok..I think its setting priority thread right?but I need to set priority to my application